# Tomcat server unable to connect with Postman after dockerise

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

[image]I wonder I'm unable to connect my app with Postman, that happens since I dockerize my app.

[image]

Server logs shows app well connected, I also connect with H2, but no success with Postman, it gives me an error:
{
"timestamp": "2021-08-29T09:08:05.775+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"path": "/"
}

What I did:
Following one stack, I deactivate SSL option. However it does not work.
I also check my other apps, these apps are able to connect with postman w/o problem.

Since there is no technical error I don't know what coding script I should bring here. For now I copy pom.xml and application.properties. Please ask if you need to see any further .java

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
 4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.eazybytes</groupId>
<artifactId>accounts</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>accounts</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

 </project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
server.port=9092
```

Comment: Is this happens when you run your project on a docker container?

Comment: Try Curl? Your browser? I fail to see how this question is about postman. Your image here isn't showing a container being ran. Please show your Docker build/run command

Comment: @OneCricketeer my project stopped producing results on postman either through docker or tomcat. I update the image & change with docker running

Comment: You have `server.port=9092`, so what are you expecting `-p 9090:9090` to do? Also, 9092 is commonly used as an Apache Kafka server port, not a webapp